# how can detect every change on input in jQuery

Tags: jquery, input, onchange

I have 2 input that i send some value from input1 to input2 i want detect when input2 is changed.

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="input1"/>
<input type="text" readonly id="input2"/>
```

JS

```
$('#input1').on("change" , function() {
  if($("#input1").val() == "550") {
     $("#input2").val("2012")
  }
  else if($("#input1").val() == "650") {
     $("#input2").val("2013")
  }
  else {
     $("#input2").val("")
  }
})
```

now i want detect when input2 have value and when is empty

this code don't work because it when happened that input have changed with keyboard or etc

```
$('#input2').on('input',function(e){
     alert('Changed!')
});
```

I need a code like that to detect every changes in input2 , thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$('#input1')
    .on('keyup input', function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        var $input2 = $('#input2');
        switch(value) {
            case "550":
                $input2
                    .val("2012");
                $input2
                    .trigger('change');
                break;
            case "650":
                $input2
                    .val("2013");
                $input2
                    .trigger('change');
                break;
            default:
                $input2
                    .val("");
        }
    });
$('#input2')
    .on('change', function(){
        alert($(this).val());
    });
```

Here is the [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vdzmpjjh/).

Comment: wonderful, thank you so much @Beginner, .trigger('change'); is my solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this:put your entire code inside `input1` input event.If you want to copmare with old `input2` value then check it before assigning new value to it.

```js
$('#input1').on('blur',function(e){
   var values="";
     if($(this).val() == 550) {
          values="2012";
}
else if($(this).val() == 650) {
   values="2013";
}
else {
   values="";
}

if($("#input2").val() == values){
alert("no change");
}else{
$("#input2").val(values);
alert("changed");
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input1"/>
<input type="text" readonly id="input2"/>
```

Comment: Thank you,I have not problem for show 2012 or 2013 in input2, i have problem to detect when input2 is changing from 2012 to 2013 or going to empty value